# CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW with Django rest framework does not work

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

Using the TokenAuthentication from DRF to authenticate the web frontend. We have a situation where some times the CSRF cookie becomes invalid due to using different URLs to access the same website. Of cause the user needs to clear the cookies before they can log in again (all expected behaviour).

Would like to delete the cookies with Django by setting the `CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW` value within the django setting and have a custom view that calls `request.session.delete()`

But...

DRF overrides the function `_reject` for the Django class `CsrfViewMiddleware` which means the setting `CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW` is never accessed.

```
class CSRFCheck(CsrfViewMiddleware):
    def _reject(self, request, reason):
        # Return the failure reason instead of an HttpResponse
        return reason
```

Any ideas as to how this can be addressed?

Comment: There are a few inconsistencies here. For one thing, ToeknAuthentication don't use CSRF token. For another, CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW is meant to show a nice error page which doesn't make sense with DRF.

Comment: Yes, TokenAuthentication does not use CSRF but it was enabled on the site by default. The fix was to actually disable CSRF and just run with TokenAuthentication as it is intended to be used.